# How to interchange column and row for non square matrix in c programming?

Tags: c, matrix

I have interchanged column and row for square matrix but can,t do non square matrix .Can anyone please help me in this ??
Here is my code for interchanging column and row for square matrix

```
 //Write a program to interchange column and row by each other.

#include<stdio.h>

//it is only valid for square matrix

int main()

{
   
 int i,j,r,c;

    printf("Enter the number of rows and columns for A= ");
    scanf("%d %d",&r,&c);
    int A[r][c],B[r][c];
   //taking input for A  matrix
   
 
for(i=0;i<r;i++)

{
     
 for(j=0;j<c;j++)
     
 {
          

printf("A[%d][%d]= ",i,j);
         

 scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
     
 }
     
printf("\n");
    
}
   

//printing A matrix
    

printf("A=\n");
   

 for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    

{
      
for(j=0;j<c;j++)
      {

          printf("%d ",A[i][j]);
      }
     printf("\n");
    }
    printf("The interchanged matrix is B\n");
    printf("Now print the interchanged matrix\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("B=\n");
    



for(i=0;i<r;i++)
   
 



{
        
  


   for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        
    {
           
    B[i][j]=A[j][i];
          
     printf("%d ",B[i][j]);
       
    }

      printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the definition of `B` be `B[c][r]` (switch `r` and `c` compared to the definition of `A`)?

Comment: You should also switch `i` and `j` in the loop where you assign to `B` from `A`.

Comment: On the other hand, do you really *need* `B`? Why not switch the place of the loops and just print from `A`?

Comment: First of all: format your code properly so it is readable. It's hard to work with poorly formatted unreadable code, even for experts.